# Swapping elements from an array that are prime numbers

Tags: arrays, c, primes, swap

I need to input my own array and give its own elements, from that array i need to print the same one but if theres a number that is prime, it needs to switch it with the next number. Example:
**My array: 4 6 3 5 7 11 13
The new array: 4 6 5 3 11 7 13**
Here prime numbers are, 3 5 7 and 13, but 13 doesnt have an element to switch itself, so it stays the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define array 100
int prime(int b
)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= b / 2; i++)
    {
        if (b % i == 0)
        {
            return b; // not prime
        }
        break;
    }
    return b;
}
int main()
{
    int n, i, a[array];
    printf("How many elements does the array have?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Put in %d elements from the array!\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    printf("My array is: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (prime(a[i]))
        {
            int temp;
            temp = prime(a[i]);
            prime(a[i]) == prime(a[i + 1]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe new array is:\n");
    printf("%d ", prime(a[i]));
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't learned pointers so is there a way without it or?

Comment: `prime(a[i]) == prime(a[i + 1]);` this line is strange

Comment: Your `prime(b)` is always equal to `b`. The primality test function should return 1 or 0 (true or false).

Comment: true, and `prime(a[i]) == prime(a[i + 1]);` is dead code, the for loop never runs

Comment: And how is `prost(a[i])` compiling, since there is no function named `prost` declared?

Comment: oxcy, Tip `for (i = 2; i <= b / 2; i++)` is slow. `for (i = 2; i <= b / i; i++)` much faster.

Comment: oxcy, `int prime(int b)` _always_ returns `b`.  Sure you want that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are few things needs to modify

1. need to change function `prime` return type to `bool`. since we are interest to check if array element is Prime. if array element is Prime, return `True`

   `int prime(int b)`

changed to

```
bool prime(int b)
```

2. also need to extend check if prime() function return true and if array index is not last element then only swap array element to next, else skip

   `if (prime(a[i]) == 1 && a[i-1] != n)`
3. `prost(a[i])` looks typo (I guess). corrected  to `a[i + 1]`
4. this is not optimized code, it just modified version of your code. if you have concern specific performance, please follow suggestion mentioned by
   chux - Reinstate Monica

code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define array 100

bool prime(int b) 
{
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= b / 2; i++) 
    {
        if (b % i == 0) 
        {
            return false; // not prime
        }
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
int main() 
{
    int n, i, a[array];
    int temp;
    printf("How many elements does the array have?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Put in %d elements from the array!\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    printf("My array is: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        if (prime(a[i]) == 1 && a[i] != a[n-1]) /* enter loop only array element is Prime number and it is not last element */
        {
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i + 1];
            a[i + 1] = temp;
        }
        a[i++];
    }
    printf("\nThe new array is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output for above code: [check out this link](https://onlinegdb.com/ykPaBM3HI)

```
How many elements does the array have?
7
Put in 7 elements from the array!
4
6
3
5
7
11
13
My array is: 
4 6 3 5 7 11 13 
The new array is:
4 6 5 3 11 7 13 

...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a for loop that only makes one iteration because of a break keyword, also in main in a for loop with your swapping you need to assign return values from the prime function to variables, and in the same function, you should use singe '=' because you want to assign value but not to compare. Also in your same for loop, you should check if(prime(a[i+1])) so there won't be any segfaults.